# Will 404 pages hurt website page ranking?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, links, 404

I have an online marketplace platform. Because of adding new products/services, I had to update my links to match the new list. Earlier, Google has indexed most of my pages. Now with the new links architecture, most of the results shown by Google are 404. I submitted new sitemap and the new links are yet to be indexed.

Question: Will 404 pages hinder my websites PageRank? If yes, how to mitigate it? Also, how can I get the new web pages indexed fast?

Please let me know your inputs, as most of my traffic is from Google search, fixing this is very important for us.

Thanks, Anji

Comment: This has been asked more times than I can count. 404's are perfectly normal if intended and even Google says this > see John's response, http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/20512/20604 if you have new pages that replace old ones and they are on topic then you should 301 them, which many topics already on Webmasters to do this. Google will index these pages as it sees fit, how important it reviews your site, social interactions, backlinks and mentions of your site speed up this process.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the 404 will hurt your ranking.

You should consider to implement a series of 301 redirects, either on your .htaccess or in your server side language, that way, users, browsers and crawlers will get the right information as soon as they try to visit the old URL.

About the speed to get the new pages indexed, that depends on the crawler itself, but you can help with the right redirection.